# JavaScript onKeyDown event in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onkeydown

I have three fields in my ReactJs application. `Quantity`, `UnitPrice` & `TotalNetPrice`. Am trying to calculate `TotalNetPrice` when we started entering any values in `Quantity` field ( `unitPrice` by default its populated ).

so, for this requirement, am using onKeyDown event. But am not getting the proper results in the `TotalNetPrice` field.

Please find my function that am using to calculate the `TotalNetPrice`

```
handleTotalPrice(e)
{   
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)
    {
        const item = this.state.item;
        const quantity = parseInt(item. quantity); 
        const price = parseInt(item.unit_net_price);
        var netAmount=0;
        if(quantity && price){
            netAmount=parseInt(quantity*price);
        }
        else{
             netAmount=0;
        }
        this.state.item.net_amount=netAmount;
        this.setState({ item: item });
    }
}
```

During the first onKeyDown event `quantity` is taking as null and during the second onKeyDown event `quantity` considering the first value that we entered previously.

Am not sure why it is happening like this.

Please find my `render()` method that am using to call the above javascript function.

```
render()
{
    return ( <tr><td><input name="quantity" type="text"  maxLength="6" onKeyDown={this.handleTotalPrice} value={ this.state.item.quantity } /></td> )
}
```

Comment: Try using onkeyup event instead of onkeydown. Or use oninput event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onkeyup instead of onkeydown.

```
    render()
{
    return ( <tr><td><input name="quantity" type="text"  maxLength="6" onKeyUp={this.handleTotalPrice} value={ this.state.item.quantity } /></td> )
}
```